# Column Index of WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using Data Grid in WPF with 3 columns.But for some reasons i have hidden the visibility of the 3rd column as Hidden.
The issue is i want to get the column index as 2 if the user clicks on 3rd column even though it is hidden.
for ex if i click on 1st column on mouseUp event i am using below code to get column index on which user has clicked.

```
DataGrid x = (DataGrid)this.FindName("ConfigGrid");
            var index = x.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex;
```

I am getting index as 0 if user clicks on first column and 1 as index if user clicks on second column.
Now the problem is if user clicks on 3rd column(Visibility is hidden) i am not getting the index of that column also.

Please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Share the xaml for your `DataGrid`.

Comment: If it's Visibility is set to Hidden then how can you click on it!?

Comment: Ali is right, visibility=hidden or collapsed means that the item will not get any mouse events. in hidden only the space is reservered. do make this work you could make it visible and use an IValueConverter to not show any values (i. e. the converter always converts to an empty string)

Comment: tell us your requirements, I believe you are trying to achieve something and trying code something entirely different (complex)

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for ur responses. My req is i've 3 columns in datagrid and I have context menu for headers.Now if i click any where in first two columns, first two columns alone should get highlight where as 3rd column should not get highlight.this is my actual requirement.but if user do right click on 3rd column it should show some context menu.  So, my req is if i click anywhere in first two columns 3rd column should not highlight and likewise if i click on 3rd column first two columns should not highlight.and my 3rd column should be readonly. so this is req. pls query me if not understood.